# Is it possible to add conditions to a variable initialization in a single line of code in C?

Tags: c, variables

I cannot quite understand this example line:

```
bool static_read = static_tactile_to_update != -1 && !CapSense_IsBusy();
```

`static_read` is initialized with a value, which is `static_tactile_to_update` (an int value between -1 and 27).
Does the `!= -1 && !CapSense_IsBusy()`
mean that `static_read` will not receive this variable if `static_tactile_to_update` is `-1`? (or if `CapSense_IsBusy()` returns `true`)

I just want to know if the `not` and `and` are used as conditions that will prevent the variable to be passed on the new value if they are not met.

Comment: Parentheses should have been used: `bool static_read = ((static_tactile_to_update != -1) && !CapSense_IsBusy());`

Comment: The value of `static_tactile_to_update != -1`  is true or false.  The same for the function

Comment: @FiddlingBits: parentheses are not necessary though some of them might clarify the interpretation of the expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right.  I should have said "Parentheses should have been used for clarity".

Answer (score 6):

Because of operator precedence, this is interpreted as

```
bool static_read = ((static_tactile_to_update != -1) && !CapSense_IsBusy());
```

It's not setting `static_read` to the value of `static_tactile_to_update`, it's setting it to the value of the comparison with `-1` and logically ANDing this with `!CapSense_IsBusy()`.

Also, because of the short-circuiting of `&&`, it will only call `CapSense_IsBusy()` if `static_tactile_to_update !- -1`.

The full logic is essentially equivalent to this:

```
bool static_read;
if (static_tactile_to_update != -1) {
    static_read = !CapSense_IsBusy();
} else {
    static_read = false;
}
```

Comment: Note: This only possible if the `static_read` has automatic storage duration.

Comment: @P__J__ You can't call a function to initialize a global variable. But you're right if it's a local static variable.

Comment: local static variables & global variables may have thread or static storage duration. There is no distinction between them in this case, except the scope. So only automatic ones can be initialized by the non constant expression (including function call of course as well)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. I mistakenly thought that local statics could be initialized dynamically.

Comment: @P__J__ I assumed your first comment implied that the function could be used to initialize something that isn't automatic.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a condition to a variable initialization, that's initializing a variable with a logical operator involved.

`static_read` is *always* assigned the result of evaluating the expression:

```
static_tactile_to_update != -1 && !CapSense_IsBusy();
```

That means the only way that is `true` is if *both* `static_tactile_to_update` is not `-1` and `CapSense_IsBusy()` returns `false`.

In every case the variable is assigned a value, it is not conditionally assigned.

Conditional assignment looks like this:

```
bool static_read;

if (...)
  static_read = true;
```

There are also no restrictions on how complex an expression can be, so you can chain on as many operators as is necessary to express the logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: Note: if the `static_tactile_to_update == -1` then `CapSense_IsBusy()` will not be executed

Comment: Note 2: This only possible if the `static_read` has automatic storage duration.